# I do not the understand why there is no output

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am trying to get a particular subset of rows from a dataset. The problem I'm facing is stated in the last paragraph. Firstly, I have done the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics 

df=pd.read_csv('Area(2).txt',delimiter='\t')
print(df.columns)
```

The dataset contains the hourly height for Area 2 measured in one month but some of the recordings/values are missing and the missing values have been recorded as "9999". Now, I want to get the rows of the heights for different time intervals. For example, below you can see how I got the height for the first 22 days and I also included the way I filtered out the missing values. This worked out fine at first. I could calculate the mean and standard deviation for this subset.

```
df2=df[df.Value!=9999]
print(df2)


# April 1-April 22 hourly height

df4=df2.iloc[0:530,5]
print(df4)
```

But when I tried to get hold of the values for the next two days, I don't get any output for some reason.

```
# April 23-April 25 hourly height
df5=df2.iloc[534:594,5]
print(df5)
```

Instead, I get the following as output instead of the required set of hourly height values like before.

```
df5=df2.iloc[534:594,5]
print(df5)
Series([], Name: Value, dtype: int64)
```

I am not sure what the part **Series([], Name: Value, dtype: int64)** means and how can I get rid of this problem to get the required subset for April 23-25? When I try to calculate the mean or standard deviation for this time interval I keep getting **nan** which should not be happening.

Comment: It is an empty series so `df2.iloc[534:594,5]` is returning an empty array essentially. Here is an example: `print(pd.Series([1,2,3,4]).iloc[4:5])`

Comment: This makes sense but in my dataset, there are at least 600 rows, and there are many recorded heights between row-534 and row-593. So shouldn't I get the subset of rows instead of an empty array? Is there anything else i can try?

Comment: Are you sure because you filter your frame? What does `print(len(df[df.Value!=9999]))` return? Are you confusing `iloc` which is the index position with `loc` which is the label-based position